# How separate are the left and right hemisphere vasculature?

Tags: neuroscience, lateralization

It appears as if there are communicating arteries between the right and left hemispheres of the brain, but it is difficult to grasp the larger picture.

**To what extent is the blood supply to each hemisphere independent from one another?**